# How can I modify the program below to accept array values?

Tags: arrays, c

Still relatively new to  programming. I wrote this program in C to enable the user to input an integer array then insert another element into a chosen position in the array. However, there is a problem with the output: the array elements are not shifted properly, resulting in the output either in the wrong order, or being random numbers. At first I thought it was a problem with me trying to increase the size of the array, but even using an array much larger than needed still gives the same error. The only way I made it work correctly is predefining the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,b;
    int in,pos;
    n=j;
    
    printf("Enter an integer greater than 0\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    
    if(n<=0)
    {
        printf("Invalid number,please re-enter\n");
        scanf("%d",&n); 
    }
    
    int arr[100];
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number: ");
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    
    printf("Your array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[i]);
    }
    n=n+1;
    
    
    printf("Enter a new integer element:\n");
    scanf("%d",&in);
    
    printf("Enter the position for it to occupy \n(Index starts from 0)\n");
    scanf("%d", &pos);
    
    if (pos> n+1)
    {
        printf("Invalid position");
    }
    
    while(j>=pos)
    {
        arr[j+1]=arr[j];
        j=j-1;  
    }
    
    arr[pos]=in;
    
    printf("Your array is now:\n");
    for(b=0;b<n+1;b++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arr[b]);
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: `int n; scanf("%d",&n); if(n<=0) ...` is potentially undefined behavior.  You *must* *always* check the value returned by scanf.  if scanf does not assign a value to n, and n was uninitialized, it is UB to attempt to evaluate n.  `scanf` has a *lot* of pitfalls, and you should avoid it completely while you are learning the language.

Comment: You should not only check n>0 but also n<=100.

Comment: `j` needs to be initialized.

Comment: Ian Abbott Thanks you made me realize my mistake, I made n=j when I should have done j=n.

Comment: Well, the `j=n` should be done after the value of `n` has been input of course. Also, I don't know why you do `n=n+1;` after printing the original array contents. The original array used indices 0 to `n-1` (for the old `n` value), so valid values for `pos` should be between 0 and `n` (for the old `n` value) inclusive.